# How to check if an array is filled enough in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check if an array is at 75% filled with objects and if it's true i have to resize it. In the variable `size` i have my objects (!=null) and i have an array of integers `ints`

```
public class PQ {

private int[] pq;
private int size;

public PQ(int capacity) {
    if (capacity < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.pq = new int[capacity + 1];
    this.size = 0;
}

public void insert(int number) {
           //Code
}


private int[] resize() {
    int[] newPQ = new int[this.pq.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.pq.length; i++) {
        newPQ[i] = this.pq[i];
    }
    return newPQ;
}
}
```

Comment: You cant check if the array is full because it is always full. The values that are not set will have a default value. This default value is what you must check for.

Comment: What is the use case? Why not use a `Collection` of some sort

Comment: Expanding on @redFIVE's comment: Is this a data structures course assignment or similar? If this is for a real software project, not a data structures exercise, then you should use a `Collection` rather than reinvent the wheel: this kind of `ArrayList`-like behaviour is already implemented in standard Java libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Whenever you add an element, we increment `size` (this will track the number of non-empty spaces so that you don't need to continually recount your array). Then we compare this number to the total length of your array. If count is at least 75% of the size of the array, we call your resize method and set pq to the new array it returns. I assume that you wish to add to the end of the array, and that you don't want empty indexs between numbers. If you want gaps you will need to use a loop which I am trying to avoid for efficiency's sake, if it isn't necessary. Assuming you don't, you can just add to your array at index `size` since this will be the first non-empty element.

```
//O(1) efficiency if you don't need to resize, O(n) if you do

public void insert(int number) {
       if(size / pq.length >= 75) {
           pq = resize();
       }
       pq[size] = number; //Since this will be the first non-empty index
       size++;
       return; //Doing it this way, if you can, is much more efficient than looping
}
```

If you call remove and take out from anything but the end you are going to have to shift everything down so that you don't have empty space.

If you are going to have empty indexes, try something like this (to insert at the first empty index encountered by the loop)...Let's use an Integer[] instead so that you can check for null and don't have to worry about any 0's in the array being counted as empty (int[] initiates everything to 0).
That way we can check for empty space and 0's are not counted as empty space in case you use any in your `int[]`.

```
    //O(n) efficiency if you don't need to resize, O(n^2) if you do

    public void insert(int number) {
           if(size / pq.length >= 75) {
               pq = resize(); 
               //You would have to make resize return an Integer[] and 
               //implement this throughout the code
           }
           for(int i = 0; i < pq.length; i++) {
                 if(pq[i] == null) {
                     pq[size] = number;
                     size++;
                     return;
                 }
           }
     }
```

**Regardless:**
Remember when you call `remove()` to decrement `size`.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is have an integer instance variable called count, that keeps track of the number of elements in the pq array. And whenever you insert an element into the array through the insert method, you can increment the count variable. Whenever you remove an element from the array through a remove method, you can decrement the count variable. Then, you can use this to check if the array is 75% filled at least,

```
if(pq.length * .75 <= size){
     //do what you need to do here
}
```

And the class would look like this,

```
public class PQ {

private int[] pq;
private int size;


public PQ(int capacity) {
    if (capacity < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.pq = new int[capacity + 1];
    this.size = 0;

}

public void insert(int number) {
           size++;
           //Code
}
public void remove(int number) {
           size--;
           //Code
}

private int[] resize() {
    int[] newPQ = new int[this.pq.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.pq.length; i++) {
        newPQ[i] = this.pq[i];
    }
    return newPQ;
}
}
```

Comment: i do have a variable for this job, its the size variable

Comment: Then, just increment size within the insert method, and decrement size within the remove method or however you decide to remove elements from the array. And in the resize method, use the if statement I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly storing the size as a variable. You also know the backing array's size. Compare them at the point when you need to check size: `if(this.size > 3*this.pq/4)`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ArrayList` do everything automatically for you in more efficient way.

**Edited:**

it is the initialization, all put -1

```
this.pq = new int[capacity + 1];
Arrays.fill(pq, -1);
```

then when you check you do like this:

```
if(pq[pq.length*.75] != -1) {
    // then is means that is has already filled up 75%
} else {
   // not filled 75% yet
}
```

Comment: How does this fit the requirements: "*I want to check if an array is at 75% filled with objects and if it's true i have to resize it.*"? What if the OP *needs* to have an array and not an `ArrayList`?

Comment: If you just want to do re-size the array, the ArrayList is re-sized automatically, if you want to do other than re-size operation, then you say clearly your question